# Calculating a CRC of a message containing integers

Tags: python, checksum, crc

I am trying to create a CRC calculator with python for a specific message to send over a RS485 cable; the frame of the message is the following:

`address | param0 | param1 | ... | param6 | CRC_L | CRC_H`.

All parameters and addresses are 8 bits integer types, this is what I have tried to do to initialize my parameters and then send it to a CRC calculation function:

```
SendData = 82
param0 = 20
param1 = 3
param2 = 7
param3 = 12
param4 = 2
param5 = 5
param6 = 2

message = Send(SendData, param0, param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6)


def Send(address, param0, param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6):

    SendStatus = False
    ReceiveStatus = False

    SendData=""
    SendData= SendData + hex(address)[2:].zfill(2)
    SendData= SendData + hex(param0)[2:].zfill(2)
    SendData= SendData + hex(param1)[2:].zfill(2)
    SendData= SendData + hex(param2)[2:].zfill(2)
    SendData= SendData + hex(param3)[2:].zfill(2)
    SendData= SendData + hex(param4)[2:].zfill(2)
    SendData= SendData + hex(param5)[2:].zfill(2)
    SendData= SendData + hex(param6)[2:].zfill(2)

    print(SendData)

    return SendData
```

In order to have a fixed length of my parameters I used zfill(2) in order to keep all hexes with 2 digits.

for example: `3` as an integer will become `0x03` and not `0x3` (which has a consequence on the structure of the message).

Finally here is what I am using to calculate the CRC:

```
crc16 = crcmod.predefined.Crc('crc-16-mcrf4xx')
crc16.update(message)
crc = crc16.hexdigest()
print(crc)
```

So this doesn't work as the `message` isn't "encoded".

What I want to avoid is my string being converted to ASCII values. Here is an example:

`0xC2`being translated to `43 32` which are the ascii caracter code of `C` and `2`. I want `crcmod` to calculate the crc of `0xC2` and not `0x43 0x32`. Hope this made my problem clearer.

EDIT: Tried to have a clearer explanation of my problem. I did found a solution which I posted below.

Comment: Huh? There are a bunch of words, but I can't make any sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem by trial and error:

`crcmod` only accepts an encoded string. So now all my parameters are initialized like this:

```
    SendData = bytes([82])
    param0 = bytes([20])
    param1 = bytes([3])
    param2 = bytes([7])
    param3 = bytes([12])
    param4 = bytes([2])
    param5 = bytes([5])
    param6 = bytes([2])

message = Send(SendData, param0, param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6)
```

so that all my integers are converted to bytes object which I will then concatenate together to create my message:

```
def Send(address, param0, param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6):

    SendStatus = False
    ReceiveStatus = False

    SendData=""
    SendData= address
    SendData= SendData + param0
    SendData= SendData + param1
    SendData= SendData + param2
    SendData= SendData + param3
    SendData= SendData + param4
    SendData= SendData + param5
    SendData= SendData + param6

    return SendData
```

Now SendData returned is a byte string and crcmod will allow it to be used.